# How to get extra claims from OpenIDConnect client login in OpenLiberty

Tags: jwt, keycloak, openid-connect, open-liberty

I'm trying to get a specific claim from an token using OpenIDConnectClient feature in open liberty.
The user is mapped correctly, as is the roles (groups claim), but I can't get the specific claim.
The OpenIDConnectClient is connecting to a KeyCloak realm.

My server.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="${project.name}">

    <featureManager>
<!--         <feature>microProfile-3.2</feature> -->
        <feature>appSecurity-3.0</feature>
        <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
        <feature>openIDConnectClient-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature>
        <feature>mpJwt-1.1</feature>
        <feature>cdi-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jwtSso-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443"/>

    <webApplication location="${project.name}.war" contextRoot="/">
        <classloader apiTypeVisibility="+third-party" />
    </webApplication>

    <openidConnectClient id="cdoMondaine"
        clientId="cdo-mondaine"
        clientSecret="****"
        discoveryEndpointUrl="https://example.server.com/auth/realms/esdl-mapeditor/.well-known/openid-configuration"
        signatureAlgorithm="RS256"
        scope="openid profile email groups user_group microprofile-jwt"
        userNameAttribute="email"
        userIdentifier="email"
        userIdentityToCreateSubject="email" 
        groupNameAttribute="groups"
        groupIdentifier="groups"
        userInfoEndpointEnabled="true"
        authFilterRef="dataUrl">
    </openidConnectClient>


    <jwtSso includeLtpaCookie="true" jwtBuilderRef="myBuilder" setCookieSecureFlag="false"></jwtSso>            
    <jwtBuilder id="myBuilder" 
        issuer="https://example.server.com/auth/realms/esdl-mapeditor"
        scope="openid profile email groups user_group microprofile-jwt">
        <claims>name,aud,user_group,groups,upn</claims>
        <audiences>cdo-mapeditor</audiences>
    </jwtBuilder>       
    <mpJwt id="myMpJwt" 
        issuer="https://example.server.com/auth/realms/esdl-mapeditor"
        jwksUri="https://example.server.com/auth/realms/esdl-mapeditor/protocol/openid-connect/certs"
        audiences="cdo-mapeditor" 
        />

    <authFilter id="dataUrl">
         <requestUrl id="requestUrl" urlPattern="/data" matchType="contains"/>
    </authFilter>

    <!-- This is the keystore that will be used by SSL and by JWT. -->
    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" location="public.p12" type="PKCS12" password="*****" />



    <!-- com.ibm.ws.webcontainer*=all:HTTPChannel=all:GenericBNF=all -->
    <logging traceSpecification="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer*=all:com.ibm.ws.security.*=all=enabled:nl.tno.*=all" /> <!-- maxFiles="8" maxFileSize="200"  -->

</server>
```

In the trace logs I see the token is correctly received (after Keycloak's login page).
As you can see I mapped the token using a jwtBuilder to a mpJWT token, but the claims are not copied.
How can I access the `user_group` claim in code? The `user_group` is a JSON array in the token.

Answer (score 0):

You may need adjust the following configuration if group claim name in id_token is "user_group". You always set groupIdentifier to the claim name.

Remove following two attributes from server.xml
        `groupNameAttribute="groups"`
        `groupIdentifier="groups"`
and replace them with 
`groupIdentifier="user_group".`

Option 1:

```
`Suject sujb = com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.getRunAsSubject();`    
`Iterate through subject, until find  com.ibm.websphere.security.cred.WSCredential`    
`use method getGroupIds() to find all groups.`
```

Option 2:
    `com.ibm.websphere.security.openidconnect.token.IdToken idToken`
    `com.ibm.websphere.security.openidconnect.PropagationHelper.getIdToken();`
    `idToken.getClaim("claim_name");`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I need both the `groups` and the `user_group` claims (groups refers to the role of the user, user_group to an arbitrary group it belongs to) and i use `groups` in `@RolesAllowed` to test the role.

Regarding your options: I started out using a microprofile app (from microprofile.io) and this makes it Liberty specific (which is not a problem currently) and these classes are not available in my maven dependencies. How could I add them?

Comment: BTW: I found this Liberty issue https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/11225, which talks about improving the API.

Comment: could you add openidConnectClient-1.0 to maven's dependency?

Comment: Yes, I overlooked that dependency. Thanks